# Old Weller replacement tips source?

Tags: soldering

I have a ~20 year old Weller station (base: 921ZX-0, iron: 9216, tip: U9960) for which I've lost all but the 9960 tip. Searches for Weller/Ungar 9960 as a starting point for finding compatible tips have proven fruitless. 20-year-old Jensen Tools catalogs are not the sort of thing Google Books ever scanned :)

Which line of modern Weller tips would be compatible with this old beast?

Comment: Checked ebay? Lots of « pattern » ones on there...

Comment: what do you mean "pattern"?

Comment: (yes, of course I checked ebay, but i can only check part numbers I know about; I would also need a list of which tips are compatible with the particular iron)

Comment: found some for mine - search and find yours...

Comment: @JayEye A pattern part is an aftermarket version of a part made by a (supposedly) licensed manufacturer. A pattern in this context is a design, perhaps more often heard of as a knitting pattern.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more searching (and more luck) uncovered this catalog: https://www.audiolabga.com/pdf/UNGAR.pdf. On page 22, I found the list of all compatible tips. *Now* I can go on ebay and search for the ones I need.

Comment: I ordered a couple from ebay and they arrived. They'll probably outlive me :)